# Save plist file not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I create a file using Xcode and give him the name **File.plist** and save as **XML**. Now to read and write this file I use the code below:

```
- (void)readPlist{

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"File" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    NSString *value;
    value = [plistDict objectForKey:@"Name"];

    NSLog(@"%@",value);

}

- (void)writeToPlist
{

    NSLog(@"Data is Writing...  ");

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"File" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    [plistDict setValue:@"StackOverflow" forKey:@"Name"];
    [plistDict writeToFile:filePath atomically: YES];

}
```

This code works very well and is very simple, but I have a problem, in viewDidLoad I execute this commands:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self readPlist];
    [self writeToPlist];
    [self readPlist];
}
```

The output is:

```
Hello World
Data is Writing...
StackOverflow
```

Great, now lets build and run again my app.... and the output is the SAME! The string **Hello World** continue appear, the correct output should be:

```
StackOverflow
Data is Writing...
StackOverflow
```

why this is happening and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can't make changes to files stored in the main bundle of the app.
You'll need to make use of the documents directory.

```
// Get the plist from the documents directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths firstObject];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"File.plist"];
NSMutableArray *content = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];


// Save plist
[content writeToFile:path atomically: YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

The application bundle in iOS is read-only.

Put your plist file into the document directory of the application.